# Common use redux's store between Nodejs and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

There are example how to create store in React:

```
//store/index.js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import reducer from '../reducer'
const store = createStore(reducer)
export default store

//components/root.js
import App from './App'
import store from '../store'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

function Root() {
    return (
        <Provider store = {store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default Root
```

So, I import 'redux' and 'react-redux'.
I wanna to create store in nodejs, then after user will be authentificated, add to store user's nick and some data, and send for user 'index.html', which written by React and will be use this store, created before. Is it possible, and how I can create store in Nodejs ? (in React I use methods {createStore}, {Provider} from 'react-redux' for this)

Comment: Do you have a seperate nodejs service handling login? Usually, you might store server-side data in a database, rather than using something like redux. Redux is for client side state management almost exclusively, if that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I have separate  nodejs service handling login. I get user's data from DB and wanna share this some info with react's other  modules. Seems it's not good idea try to use Redux. So, if I after successful login, wanna give for client index.html (with <script>src="....foo.js"</script>, written using react) some data, got from MongoDB (nick, data), how it possible to transfer app's controle to Redux ? If it's not redux's store, how can I transfer user's data (name, age, score,etc)

Comment: I'm assuming the response from login contains the data you're looking to save in the redux store? A typical flow for redux would be.. On successful login an loginSucess action is created, with a payload of the information you want to save, a redux reducer when then pick up that action and save it in the store. There's a pretty full example here - https://react-redux.herokuapp.com